# Params Not being passed to AJAX correctly - Encoding issue?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Here is my code:

```
var params = '_SaveEditUserReq=1' ;
for(i=0; i<document.editUserForm.elements.length; i++)
{
    // if(document.editUserForm.elements[i].name.substr(0, 7) == "school|") {
    if (document.editUserForm.elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
        // If the id begins with 'school|', take the value if it is checked.
        if (document.editUserForm.elements[i].checked) {
            console.log("CHECKED!" + document.editUserForm.elements[i].value);
            params += "&" + encodeURIComponent(document.editUserForm.elements[i].name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(document.editUserForm.elements[i].value) ;
            console.log(params);
        }

    } 
    else {
        // Take everything else
        params += "&" + document.editUserForm.elements[i].name + "=" + document.editUserForm.elements[i].value ;
    }
}
```

Here is what is being built:

```
SaveEditUserReq=1&_username=jgald&_orig_username=jgald&password_error_msg=&new_password_ok=YES&new_password=&new_password_text=&new_password_too=&new_password_too_text=&_last_name=TheSirName&_first_name=TheName&_middle_initial=&_profile=Teacher&_email=email@email.com&_teacher=&school%7C=Baker%20Elementary%20School&school%7C=Brookland%20Middle%20School&school%7C=Charles%20M.%20Johnson%20Elementary%20School&=SAVE CHANGES&=CANCEL&_site=TheSite
```

When it's passed to `PHP`, the `$_POST` array only sees the last `checkbox` checked.

In this case:

```
[school|] => Charles M. Johnson Elementary School
```

Can you see what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given multiple key/value pairs with the same name, PHP will discard all but the last one unless the key name ends with the characters `[]`.

If those characters exist, then it will populate `$_GET` (or post, etc) with an array where the name doesn't include `[]`.

i.e.

```
foo.php?bar%5B%5D=1&bar%5B%5D=2
```

will give:

```
$_GET['foo'][0] == 1;
$_GET['foo'][1] == 2;
```

Comment: Are you talking about in the HTML, such as name='School[]'?

Comment: I'm talking about the data encoded in the URL (or post body) but (since you are populating that data by reading the names of the inputs) it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: Here is the checkboxes HTML: `sprintf("<input type=checkbox %s name=\"school|\" value=\"%s\">\n", $checked, $school)`

Comment: Yes, so put `[]` on the end of the name.

Comment: Thanks,that appears to be it.

Answer (score 0):

From the JavaScript portion, you have two problems

**Encoding the name**

You do not encode the name, just the value

```
 params += "&" + encodeURIComponent(document.editUserForm.elements[i].name)
```

should be

```
 params += "&" + document.editUserForm.elements[i].name
```

**Not encoding the value in  else**

You are not encoding the value in the else!

```
"=" + document.editUserForm.elements[i].value ;
```

needs to be

```
"=" + encodeURIComponent(document.editUserForm.elements[i].value) ;
```

Comment: This is true, and could potentially cause issues (depending on the name and value of the inputs) but isn't the cause of the problem here.